# Webapp timestamps being auto converted to UTC on Mobile Phones

Tags: c#, datetime, mobile, web-applications, utc

We have a web application written in C# that has a mobile view, and on there we display timestamps for various data points and nodes. When the mobile view for the application is viewed through a desktop, the timestamps display fine. However, when they are viewed on a mobile phone, the timestamps are being converted/displayed in UTC.

We store our timestamps in UTC and convert them to local time in the views. It has also been observed that occasionally the timestamps will display correctly on a phone, however it will not stay like that consistently. Any ideas on why this is happening? Issue is across multiple phones/operating systems/browsers. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have been experiencing this for years too: Creation-timestamp on photos and videos are stored in UTC/GMT no matter where you live. At first I assumed it was a bug specifically for my phone model, but it's proven to stick with me - and I recently discovered that it seems to apply to all cellphones. Normal cameras doesn't behave like this - only cellphones. Some kind of explanation would be nice.